# What are my options - sql express or?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a client who has a VB 6.0 application with MS Access as backend. But, now the Access is unable to take the load. So, we are now considering to shift to SqlExpress Edition. Also, we will convert VB6.0 application to c# based Winforms. My questions -

1) Can SqlserverExpress support 10 users concurrently? If not SqlExpress, then what other options are available?

2) Should I first convert VB 6.0 to C# application? Because, if I transfer data to Sqlserver, will VB 6.0 application continue to work?

thanks

Comment: Yes SQL Express is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes it can
2. You don't need to convert your app, but Access and Sql Express - are different database engines, so you will need to adopt your app to sql express
3. Note, that sql express prior to 2008 R2 can handle up to 4 Gb databases, while 2008 R2 can handle up to 10 Gb per database.

Answer (score 1):

1) SQL Express allows over 32 thousand simultaneous users.  The only real limit is database size, which is 10 Gigabytes.

2) You'll need to at least modify the VB 6 application to have the correct connection string before it will work with SQL server.

I am curious though why you say that Access (the JET database engine) is unable to take the load.  Usually 20 or even more simultaneous users are no problem.

Comment: Oh , I did not know Access can take such a load. I will try to figure out why the load is becoming an issue. At present, I don't have access either to the code or the database. So, as a starting point, I will look into the reasons for Access being unable to take the load.

Answer (score 0):

If product is for in house use and doesnt generate cash you can use oracle. Its free to use unless your app is for commercial use.

Answer (score 0):

One question to ask is after how many users does the system slow down? And if it is slow with one user, then this might be some software design issue and not necessary the "load" on the server. There also the issue of the type of connection WAN or LAN.  In fact you can read about this issue in the following article:

http://www.kallal.ca//Wan/Wans.html

The above in a nutshell explains why the Access data engine does not work well on a WAN.

Also migration of data to SQL server without determining what particular issue is causing the slowdown could very well result in a further slowdown. In other words often just up-sizing data to a server database engine will not solve performance issues and in some cases it can become worse.

In fact in many on line Access forums we often see users complain of a slowdown when moving the back end data file from Access to SQL server. So just moving to SQL server without taking advantages of SQL server features does not always guarantee a performance boost.

The other issue you want to determine here is if the VB6 program uses ADO or DAO. Either data object model is fine, but ADO would suggest LESS code will have to be modified then if the application is based on DAO.

Another issue is you not mentioned how large tables are, and the number. So say 30 to 50 highly related tables, and say a small number of rows (say 200,000) in some of the tables should run just fine with 5 to 15 users.  If your user count is only about 10, and your table row counts are small as noted then performance should be ok, and if it is not, then as noted you might be able to keep the application as is and moving the data to SQL server may not yield performance gains without further code modifications. And of course SOME code will have to be modified to work with SQL server - how much will depend on the data object used, and how much code there is over all. (more recordset code = more chance of needing more code changes).

Answer (score 0):

If you do decide to convert from Access to SQL Server Express, there is a migration wizard which can give you a quick start with that process.  Here's the [link](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/product-info/migration-tool.aspx#Access)